# Superbundles and spin in Dirac equation

Tags: quantum-spin, dirac-equation, superalgebra

The Dirac operator $D$ of a Clifford bundle $S$ is a first order differential operator on $C^{\infty}(S)$.

The Clifford bundles considered are $\mathbb{Z} / 2 \text { -graded }$ (superbundles). This means $S$ is provided with a direct sum decomposition $S= S_{+}\oplus S_{-}$.

In terms of a local ortonormal basis $e_{i}$ and $s\in C^{\infty}(S)$, we have:

$$
D s=\sum_{i} e_{i} \nabla_{i} s
$$

Dirac operator is odd: maps sections of $S_{+}$ to sections of $S_{-}$ and vice versa.

**Question** I don't know if it is about notation but I suspect that there is a relation between superbundles and the spin in the Dirac equation. If this relation exists, what it is?

Answer (score 1):

The $S_\pm$ subbundles correspond to the two inequivalent irreducible two-dimensional spin representations of ${\rm SO}(4)$, or more correctly ${\rm Spin}(4)$.